# output variable stored in database

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm storing the page content in a database table.  The page content also includes some CF variables (for example "...this vendor provides services to #VARIABLES.vendorLocale#").

VARIABLES.vendorLocal is set on the page based on a URL string.

Next a CFC is accessed to get the corresponding page text from the database.

And this is then output on the page:  #qryPageContent.c_content#

But #VARIABLES.vendorLocale# is showing up as is, not as the actual variable.  Is there anyway to get a "variable within a variable" to be output correctly?

This is on a CF9 server.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string i.e.

```
variables.vendorLocal = 'foo';
variables.saveMe = 'This is a string for supplier "#variables.vendorLocal#'"' ;
WriteOutput(variables.saveMe); // This is a string for locale "foo"
```

then coldfusion will attempt to parse that to insert whatever variable variables.vendorLocale is.  To get around this, you can use a placeholder string that is not likely to be used elsewhere.  Commonly you'll see [[NAME]] used for this purpose, so in this example

```
variables.saveMe = 'This is a string for supplier "[[VENDORLOCALE]]'"' ;
WriteOutput(variables.saveMe); // This is a string for supplier "[[VENDORLOCALE]]"
```

Now you've got that you can then later on replace it for your value

```
variables.vendorLocal = 'bar';
variables.loadedString = Replace(variables.saveMe,'[[VENDORLOCALE]]',variables.vendorLocal);
WriteOutput(variables.loadedString); // This is a string for locale "bar"
```

I hope this is of help

Comment: Strange - as soon as I used Evaluate (either in cfscript or regular tags) I get an error:  Invalid CFML construct found on line 1 at column 1.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

<

The CFML compiler was processing:

    < marks the beginning of a ColdFusion tag.Did you mean LT or LTE?

Comment: Then you likely have a < within the evaluated string potentially.  An alternative is to just for example type 'This is a locale [[LOCALE]]'; and then do a Replace() to replace [[LOCALE]] with the locale @ rendering time.  This is probably a better method (I'm not keen on Evaluate when avoidable) and so have updated my example

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of reasons storing code itself in the database is a bad idea, but that's not your question, so I won't go into that.  One way to accomplish what you want is to take the code you have stored as as string, write a temporary file, include that file in the page, then delete that temporary file.  For instance, here's a little UDF that implements that concept:

```
<cfscript>
  function dynamicInclude(cfmlcode){
    var pathToInclude = createUUID() & ".cfm";
    var pathToWrite = expandPath(pathToInclude);
    fileWrite(pathToWrite,arguments.cfmlcode);
    include pathToInclude;
    fileDelete(pathToWrite);
  }

  language = "CFML";
  somecfml = "This has some <b>#language#</b> in it";
  writeOutput(dynamicInclude(somecfml));
</cfscript>
```